# Why isn't my checkout button and form not communicating with stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm having trouble getting my "submit (checkout button)" to go to the stripe checkout page for an e-commerce site I'm building. I'm following the [Custom payment flow](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart)
 and wondering if I am missing any steps possibly?

I have provided my code below which includes the server.js, checkout.js, and index.html:

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
// This is your test secret API key.
const stripe = require("stripe")('sk_test_XXXXXXXX');

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

const calculateOrderAmount = (items) => {
    [1, { priceInCents: 8500, name: "Black Sweatsuit"}],
    [2, { priceInCents: 8500, name: "Grey Sweatsuit"}],
    [3, { priceInCents: 8500, name: "Red Sweatsuit"}],
    [4, { priceInCents: 8500, name: "Blue Sweatsuit"}]

  return 1400;
};

app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { items } = req.body;
  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    mode: "payment", 
    currency: "usd",
    automatic_payment_methods: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  });

  // const endpointSecret = "whsec_93f2310c53f1bdbb9496049a38ea5ceadbce03fcf4223b2be51c5b6717f2cc60";

  // app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  //   const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
  
  //   let event;
  
  //   try {
  //     event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
  //   } catch (err) {
  //     response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  //     return;
  //   }
  
  //   // Handle the event
  //   switch (event.type) {
  //     case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
  //       const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
  //       // Then define and call a function to handle the event payment_intent.succeeded
  //       break;
  //     // ... handle other event types
  //     default:
  //       console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  //   }

  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
  });

  const endpointSecret = "whsec_93f2310c53f1bdbb9496049a38ea5ceadbce03fcf4223b2be51c5b6717f2cc60";

app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    return;
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a function to handle the event payment_intent.succeeded
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }

  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.send();
});


app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

**checkout.js**

```
// This is your test publishable API key.
const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_XXXXX");

// The items the customer wants to buy
const items =  [{ id: "Black Sweatsuit"}]
               [{ id: "Grey Sweatsuit"}]
               [{ id: "Red Sweatsuit"}]
               [{ id: "Blue Sweatsuit"}];

let elements;

initialize();
checkStatus();

document
  .querySelector("#payment-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
  const response = await fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ items }),
  });
  const { clientSecret } = await response.json();

  const appearance = {
    theme: 'stripe',
  };
  elements = stripe.elements({ appearance, clientSecret });

  const paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
  paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}

async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);

  const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
      return_url: "http://localhost:4242/checkout.html",
    },
  });

  // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
  // confirming the payment. Otherwise, your customer will be redirected to
  // your `return_url`. For some payment methods like iDEAL, your customer will
  // be redirected to an intermediate site first to authorize the payment, then
  // redirected to the `return_url`.
  if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
    showMessage(error.message);
  } else {
    showMessage("An unexpected error occurred.");
  }

  setLoading(false);
}

// Fetches the payment intent status after payment submission
async function checkStatus() {
  const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
    "payment_intent_client_secret"
  );

  if (!clientSecret) {
    return;
  }

  const { paymentIntent } = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret);

  switch (paymentIntent.status) {
    case "succeeded":
      showMessage("Payment succeeded!");
      break;
    case "processing":
      showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
      break;
    case "requires_payment_method":
      showMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
      break;
    default:
      showMessage("Something went wrong.");
      break;
  }
}

// ------- UI helpers -------

function showMessage(messageText) {
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#payment-message");

  messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
  messageContainer.textContent = messageText;

  setTimeout(function () {
    messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    messageText.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
}

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
</div> 
                        <div class="subtotal">Subtotal: $0.00</div>
                        <form id="payment-form">
                            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter email address" />
                            <div id="payment-element">
                              <!--Stripe.js injects the Payment Element-->
                            </div>
                            <button id="submit">
                              <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
                              <span id="button-text">Checkout</span>
                            </button>
                            <div id="payment-message" class="hidden"></div>
                          </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I recommend editing your post to remove your publishable key and webhook endpoint secret.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at `stripe.paymentIntents.create`: you'll need to use either `payment_method_types` or `automatic_payment_methods`, not both.

Separately, `calculateOrderAmount` will always return `1400` in the above code. This shouldn't cause any issues with the creation of the PaymentIntent and rendering the PaymentElement, but just wanted to call this out.

Edit: I spotted a few more things:

- In checkout.js, the syntax for `items` is incorrect. There should be a single set of open and close brackets, and each item should be separated by a comma:

```
const items = [{ id: "Black Sweatsuit"},
               { id: "Grey Sweatsuit"},
               { id: "Red Sweatsuit"},
               { id: "Blue Sweatsuit"}];
```

- In server.js, `mode` should be removed altogether. `mode` is specifically for Stripe's Checkout product only. As mentioned above, the PaymentIntent creation call should be edited to also use `payment_method_types` or `automatic_payment_methods`, not both.
- In index.html, make sure you're including the following scripts (this is probably in your file already, above the code you shared):

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="checkout.js" defer></script>
```

This assumes `checkout.js` is located in your `public` folder.

Comment: Didn't change the result at all. Honestly, need help can I push this to you on Github if you have time?

Comment: @Royce I updated the answer above! Hope this helps.